# Else statement is not being executed - Unix

Tags: if-statement, unix, awk

I am trying to run a bash script that has an if/else condition, but for some reason, my `else` statement is not being executed.

The rest of the script works perfectly. I could try to make it different, but I am trying to understand why this `else`  is not working.

```
n=1
 for ((i=1;i<=GEN;i++))
 do
  if [ `cat sires${i} | wc -l` -ge 0 ] || [ `cat dams${i} | wc -l` -ge 0 ]; then
      cat sires${i} dams${i} > parent${i}
      awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next} {if($1 in a) print a[$1]; else print $0}' ped parent${i} >> ped_plus
      cat ped_plus | awk '$2!=0 {print $2,0,0}' | awk '!a[$1]++' > tmp_sire
      cat ped_plus | awk '$3!=0 {print $3,0,0}' | awk '!a[$1]++' > tmp_dam
      ((n2=n+i))
      awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} !($1 in a) {print $0}' ped_plus tmp_sire > sires${n2}
      awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} !($1 in a) {print $0}' ped_plus tmp_dam > dams${n2}
  else
      echo "Your file looks good."
      i=99
  fi
 done
```

It should print the message `Your file looks good.` , but this is not happing.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's not just taking the `if` branch every time instead of the `else`?

Comment: when will `wc -l` ever return a value less than zero?

Comment: you can use `break` instead of `i=99`

Comment: I am looking for the parents (in ped) of a list of individuals (parents).    When all of them are already in the file ```ped_plus```, ```sires${n2}``` and ```dams${n2}```  should be empty and then ```wc -l``` will be zero.

Comment: I will use ```break``` instead of ```i=99```.   Thank you.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy - Yeah, I believe that it is not taking the ```else``` statement, but I don't know why.

Comment: ge = greater or equals, gt = greater than. Your test is always true because you are testing >=0...

Comment: Ouch. That's true. Right on my face and I couldn't see it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-gt`, not `-ge` when you want to check for more than 0.
Or look at `man test`, you will find the  option `-s`:

```
if [ -s sires${i} ] || [ -s dams${i} ]; then
```